# Why is microcosmic salt called so?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

I really see no relation between the terms microcosmic and the salt's structural formula, $\ce{Na(NH4)HPO4.4H2O}$.

Devoting sufficient time on Google didn't help at all.

Information about the name of this compound is what I'm searching for, thanks in advance for sharing.

Comment: From Meriam Webster Dictionary Online

translation of New Latin sal microcosmicus; from the fact that it was originally obtained from human urine- still not  enough  information to discern the link between microcosmicus and urine.

Answer (score 4):

> Devoting sufficient time on Google didn't help at all.

Hmmm... I found [this PDF](http://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/geol/fachrichtungen/geochemhydromin/mineralogie/pdf/quickassay.pdf) in just a few seconds, where we read the following.

> The origin of the name microcosmic salt.
>
> Beads of sodium metaphosphate
> saturated with some oxides cool to a clear glass. Small crystals grow
> in the glass on repeated heating and cooling. A microscope with a 80
> to 100 x magnification is needed to inspect these crystals with
> various morphologies. Such beads resemble a microcosmos. Some authors
> tried to use the effect for analytical purposes in the 19th century,
> but these efforts failed. Borax beads sometimes show the same effect.

Microcosmos here is understood (as usual) as a "small world", a "world in miniature".